# 400 Bad request on Spring ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm getting an error in spring ajax call. I know it's some syntax error but cant find what's it. can someone help?

script:

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: 'saveCommittedAmount.html?investmentId='+investmentId+ '&=transactionData' +transactionData + '&=investorId' +investorId + '&committedAmt='+committedAmt,
        success: function(response) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveCommittedAmount", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String saveInvestmentValue(@RequestParam("investmentId") String investmentId,
            @RequestParam("transactionDate") String transactionDate,@RequestParam("investorId") String investorId,
            @RequestParam("committedAmt") String committedAmt) throws ParseException {
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction();

        Date tDate = (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(transactionDate.trim());

        transaction.setCommittedAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(committedAmt)));
        transaction.setUserId(Integer.parseInt(investorId));
        System.out.println("committedAmt" + "committedAmt");
        transaction.setTransActDate(tDate);
        transaction.setInvestmentId(Integer.parseInt(investmentId));
        assetService.updateTransaction(transaction);
        return Constants.RESPONSE_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `saveInvestmentValue` method expects a `@RequestParam("transactionDate")`.

However, your ajax call sends `transactionData`. You should change this to be the same

```
 url: 'saveCommittedAmount.html?investmentId='+investmentId+ '&=transactionDate' +transactionDate + '&=investorId' +investorId + '&committedAmt='+committedAmt,
```

Comment: sorry, the project wasnt clean, it worked after cleaning the project, thanks again.